# Why large pandas dataframe shows only NaN values after I drop selected rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using the pandas library v. 17.1, I am trying to remove the rows from a large (882504 rows) dataframe named `productDataNat` where `parName`=='rt', but then all the other rows become `NaN`:

```
productDataNat = pd.read_csv('https://lobianco.org/temp/productData_P0-Mi-Ei.csv',sep=';',  dtype={'value': np.float64})
productDataNat = productDataNat.drop(['Unnamed: 8'],axis=1)
productDataNat.set_index(['scen','country','region','prod','freeDim','year','parName'], inplace=True)
productDataNat.head()
```

[image: out1]

```
productDataNat.drop('rt', level='parName', axis=0)
```

[image]

When instead I play with an example dataframe it works as expected:

```
midx = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['one', 'two'], ['x','y']], labels=[[1,1,1,0],[1,0,1,0]])
dfmix = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [5, 6, 7, 8]}, index=midx)
dfmix
```

[image]

```
dfmix.drop('x',level=1,axis=0)
```

[image]

Bug in pandas or something wrong (what?) with my dataframe ?

Comment: So this issue was submitted as a bug report this question: [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/12754). The level ``freeDim`` has ``NaN's`` in it, when the labels are dropped from ANOTHER level, then the remaining indexing has only NaN's on that level. The way this is done internally it causes a reindex and nothing matches, hence ``NaNs``.

Answer (score 0):

Correction:
It works exactly the same  for me (i'm using Pandas v0.18.0):

```
In [4]: df.drop('rt', level='parName', axis=0)
Out[4]:
                                                          value
scen     country region prod        freeDim year parName
P0-Mi-Ei 11000   11042  hardWRoundW NaN     2005 dl         NaN
                        softWRoundW NaN     2005 dl         NaN
                        pulpWFuelW  NaN     2005 dl         NaN
                        ashRoundW   NaN     2005 dl         NaN
                        fuelW       NaN     2005 dl         NaN
                        hardWSawnW  NaN     2005 dl         NaN
                        softWSawnW  NaN     2005 dl         NaN
                        plyW        NaN     2005 dl         NaN
                        pulpW       NaN     2005 dl         NaN
                        pannels     NaN     2005 dl         NaN
                        ashSawnW    NaN     2005 dl         NaN
                        ashPlyW     NaN     2005 dl         NaN
                 11061  hardWRoundW NaN     2005 dl         NaN
                        softWRoundW NaN     2005 dl         NaN
                        pulpWFuelW  NaN     2005 dl         NaN
                        ashRoundW   NaN     2005 dl         NaN
                        fuelW       NaN     2005 dl         NaN
                        hardWSawnW  NaN     2005 dl         NaN
                        softWSawnW  NaN     2005 dl         NaN
                        plyW        NaN     2005 dl         NaN
                        pulpW       NaN     2005 dl         NaN
                        pannels     NaN     2005 dl         NaN
                        ashSawnW    NaN     2005 dl         NaN
                        ashPlyW     NaN     2005 dl         NaN
                 11072  hardWRoundW NaN     2005 dl         NaN
                        softWRoundW NaN     2005 dl         NaN
                        pulpWFuelW  NaN     2005 dl         NaN
                        ashRoundW   NaN     2005 dl         NaN
                        fuelW       NaN     2005 dl         NaN
                        hardWSawnW  NaN     2005 dl         NaN
```

as a workaround you can get rid of `rt`s before setting multiindex:

```
cols = 'scen;parName;country;region;prod;freeDim;year;value'.split(';')
url = 'https://lobianco.org/temp/productData_P0-Mi-Ei.csv'
productDataNat = pd.read_csv(url, sep=';', dtype={'value': np.float64}, usecols=cols)

df = productDataNat.ix[productDataNat.parName != 'rt']

df.set_index(['scen','country','region','prod','freeDim','year','parName'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: yes, removing 'rt' rows before setting the index is the way I did.. I then assume it's a bug in 0.17 that has been fixed in 0.18.. thanks

Comment: @Antonello, sorry i have removed all `rt`s before testing it - now I've updated my answer